Can I get the type (class) of a table using SQLite in C#?
I have multiple tables for separate classes and want to print their data using a single method.
My code so far.
In the while (reader.Read()) loop the program doesnt enter the if statements (reader.GetType() == typeof(T).GetType())
I guess its because the reader.GetType() returns a string because thats the data in the tables. What I want it to do is to find out which table it is reading from so I can create Lists of the correct class to return to the user.
public static (List<T>, List<U>) ViewInventory<T, U>()
        where T : class, new()
        where U : class, new()
    {
        List<T> tableDataT = new();
        List<U> tableDataU = new();

        using (var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var tableCmd = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                // Get from all tables
                tableCmd.CommandText =
                    "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' ORDER BY 1";

                using (var reader = tableCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {                        
                        // Read product database
                        if (reader.GetType() == typeof(T).GetType())
                        {
                            T model = new();

                            foreach (var prop in (typeof(T).GetProperties()))
                            {
                                prop.SetValue(model, reader[prop.Name]);
                            }
                            tableDataT.Add(model);
                        }

                        // Read service database
                        if (reader.GetType() == typeof(U).GetType())
                        {
                            U model = new();

                            foreach (var prop in (typeof(T).GetProperties()))
                            {
                                prop.SetValue(model, reader[prop.Name]);
                            }
                            tableDataU.Add(model);                          
                        }
                    }
                    return (tableDataT, tableDataU);
                }
            }
        }
    }


You might want to check out a Object Relational Mapper, like Entity Framework. That can take care of converting rows to objects for you.

"to find out which table it is reading from", you wrote the query, why didn't you know?

reader.GetType() always returns Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.
